# how to specify Qt plugin constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, interface, constructor, plugins

I wonder if it is possible to specify a constructor in a Qt plugin interface? (extending an app)

I want to force the plugins using the interface to take a parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to do exactly what you described.

However, you might try to create factory object and then pass parameters to YourFactory::create() method, which returns pointer to YourObject. Another (uglier IMHO) way is to add initialize() method to YourObject. Check interfaces of [QFontEnginePlugin](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qfontengineplugin.html) and [QScriptExtensionPlugin](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qscriptextensionplugin.html) for both approaches.